# How strong CodeIgniter is comparing to Zend Framework? especially for developing a hotels directory portal

Tags: zend-framework, codeigniter, portal

When I decided to start using php framework, I have gone for CodeIgniter because of I didn't have much learning time, I had strict project dead-line. I actually wanted Zend Framework so much. I'm happy with CI so far... But I'm about to start a big hotels directory project like kayak.com . My project will not have so big db of course, but structure will be similar.

Now I worry if I make mistake to start such project with CI :-S Would it be pain in ass at the project development process. I'm not sure how strong and reliable CI is for such projects :/

I appreciate advices so much!! thanks!!

Comment: If you select the best (suitable) answer by the green tick ;)

Comment: aha! thanks :D i will do that for all my questions from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both have there pros and cons, ZF is a much stricter framework the CI, in that CI themselves say that you need not use models (which is a bad habit to get into). Zend has far greater supporting libraries, the authentication libraries for CI are pretty poor to be honest,  while zends authentication is pretty, it comes with an ACL library as part of its core.  My choice would be Zend.

====In response to your comment=====

I would think that if you have used CI then you have some knowledge about MVC even if you CI has put you in a habit of using it badly.  Zend has amazing documentation and support so any stumbling blocks you may reach in the convertion from CI to Zend would easily be solved.  It may cause a few sleepless nights, but surely that is small price to pay for adding another feather to your cap?

Comment: actually no doubt Zend is more advanced comparing to CI. So you say, CI would not be good choice for such project... On the other hand, I will give almost 2 times more time-line for project if I choose Zend, It will be my first project with Zend, and I will have to learn Zend with this project. so, you think it worths to give so much effort and sleepless nights? ps, I hope it will not be so difficult to learn Zend for a coder who knows CI, they are kind of similar system as i know. ?

Comment: I actually need to be encouraged to start using ZEND :) CI and Zend has same MVC structure and both are php framework... so how much difficult can it be to learn one of them for a coder already knows one... I think it is my time to go for Zend! At least I feel that I can rely 100% on Zend for future, it always will be supported by zend. but I dont feel so good about CI future :/ thanks for comments. I've just already started with the link http://files.zend.com/webinar/framework-20070725-overview/framework-20070725-overview.html :D

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to stick with what you know, that is the best way to get the project done. Since you already did a project with CI you should know CI better :)

Comment: I generally build small scope projects with CI and I didn't have any problem such such scope projects. My worrying is about big projects and CI :/

Comment: What is there to worry about? My advice is to try and build a small project utilizing most of the components of ZF you plan to use on this project and see if it fits you. I have never worked with CI and I use ZF, but there is no way I would try out a new framework while building a complex site.

Answer (score 0):

I use Codeigniter in sites with average 65.000 access by day, if you know how to use cache systems, and you know how to optimize your databases structure and topology. Well CI is very very good, easy to install, fast, good and active comunity and not heavy.

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: what kind of sites are they? portal-like? can you please give some links here... Thanks!